# CopyFromRecordset Not Working

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, ado.net, vba

Hi I Inserted A Select MaxID+1 Data and want to retrieve what was that ID I inserted the Following is the codes

Im trying to Insert data from Excel to Ms Access and Automatically Retrieve that Data.
For MultiUser Purpose I need to retrieve specifically the data I inserted.

```
Sub PostData()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset classe here
Dim dbPath
Dim x As Long, i As Long

'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:

dbPath = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("h1").Value

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
Sql = "INSERT INTO DvID(DVnumber)SELECT Max(DVNumber)+1 FROM DvID "
rst.Open Sql, cnn
Sheet3.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
cnn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to DBA StackExchange.  It is not clear what your question is--are you getting an error?  If it's not getting an error, what is the result it is returning, and what is the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally Figure it out.

```
Do
On Error Resume Next 'reset Err.obj.

 'Get the Max ID +1
Set rst = Nothing
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
SQL = "SELECT Max(ApNumber)+1 FROM PayVoucherID "
rst.Open SQL, cnn

'Check if the recordset is empty.
'Copy Recordset to the Temporary Cell
Sheets("MAX").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

'Insert the Data to Database And Check If no Errors
Sql2 = "INSERT INTO PayVoucherID(ApNumber)Values('" & Sheets("MAX").Range("A2") & "') "
cnn.Execute Sql2
Loop Until (Err.Number = 0)}
```